# Formatting textbox contents

Tags: .net, powershell, winforms

i'm trying to create a gui script for our helpdesk to use to grant users share permissions. I'm currently stuck at textbox with share paths, i want it to accept input, upon "Textchange" event, validate paths and then change text so only valid paths are left and invalid ones would be deleted. The event looks like this:

```
$Pathbox.Add_Textchanged({
#$PathsToGrant = @()
$this.Text -split '\r?\n' -ne '' | ForEach-Object {
     if ($_ -match "C:" -or $_ -match "ProgramFile" -or $_ -match "D:" -or $_ -match "Appdata")
     {
     $msgboxinput =[System.Windows.Messagebox]::Show("Some text",'Warning','Ok','Warning')
     $mod = "(0,666)"
     }
 elseif (-not$(Test-Path -Path $_))
     { 
     $msgboxinput =[System.Windows.Messagebox]::Show("Some Text",'Warning','Ok','Warning')
     $mod = "(0,666)"
     }
 else 
     {
     $PathsToGrant += $_
     #Write-Host $PathsToGrant
     }
     }
     Write-Host $PathsToGrant.Count
     $PathBox.Text = ""
     $PathBox.Text = $PathsToGrant 
                           })
```

I've been adviced here to use $this.Text -split '\r?\n' -ne '' so my textbox would behave like an array instead of 1 long string, but when i try to rewrite the Textbox's text at the end with legit values - it just inserts 2 array objects as 1 row anyway and it creates broken cycle.
Maybe i should not have used textbox control in the firt place ? Are there any other more suitable controls for theese kinds of things ? Thank You.

Comment: The code you've posted is invalid, there's a closing `"` missing after `$mod = "(0,666)`

Comment: Can you describe the current behavior in more detail? "it just inserts 2 array objects as 1 row" - what do you mean by "1 row"? It's a text box, not a spreadsheet :)

Comment: Maybe it's a useless remark but did you set your textbox to be multilines? (it's a property of the TextBox controls)

Comment: Sure did it works properly untill i try to Clear all text and insert values that have passed Test-path at the very bottom there.

Comment: Mathias, well the variable $PathsToGrant is an array and contains 2 items, let's say it's "Hello" and "There", but when i do $PathBox.Text = $PathsToGrant, $PathBox.Text becomes "Hello There", therefore as cycle goes through this again, since text changes, this path is invalid already, it should be like : Hello, new line There so it would see 2 separate values as valid paths instead of 2 valid paths combined, resulting in mess.

Comment: is this what you want to achieve ? `$Pathbox.Multiline = $true` and `$PathBox.Text = $PathsToGrant -join "\`r\`n"`. However, as a textbox, no choice can be done by selecting one line.

Comment: Cfou, if i add $PathBox.Text = $PathsToGrant -join "`r`n" it still does see theese 2 values as one long string for some reason anyway, but generally yes, i want text in textbox to be deleted and i want 2 values from $PathsToGrant to be placed there instead as 2 lines.

Comment: have you setted the multiline attribute like this `$Pathbox.Multiline = $true` ? I have just tested with a test texbox, and array is well shown on two lines. Be aware of the textbox height too.

Comment: CFou, yes i have, and it's high enough to fit ~ 8 Lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$PathsToGrant` is a string, not an array. When you add your path like this :

```
$PathsToGrant += $_
```

it is likely you write

```
$PathsToGrant = $PathsToGrant + "new path"
```

this is because you have commented your variable declaration, since the first value for `$PathsToGrant` is a string, the variable becomes a string. So uncomment the second line

```
$PathsToGrant = @()
```

If for some reason that I don't understand, it is a problem for you, then add the path within an array like this

```
$PathsToGrant += , $_
```

(the comma is important). No need to do the last if you declare your array (which is best for me)

finally, ensure that your textbox is multiline

```
 $Pathbox.Multiline = $true
```

and set the text with a join :

```
$PathBox.Text = $PathsToGrant -join "`r`n"
```

However, as a textbox, no choice can be done by selecting one line. You may prefer a listbox (but you cannot type any value) :

```
$listbox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listbox1.DataSource = $PathsToGrant
```

EDIT: if `$PathsToGrant` is already declared at the start of the script, the `$PathsToGrant` inside your function is not in the same scope, so it is considered as a new variable when you are setting the value. If this variable needs to be script wide, then keep your variable declaration as commented inside the function `$Pathbox.Add_Textchanged` :

```
#$PathsToGrant = @()
```

and add the values on the script scope variable this way :

```
$script:PathsToGrant += $_
```

you should usually avoid this, but gui scripts can be considered as an exception, especially for event functions to which you cannot pass arguments as you want.

Comment: Thanks CFou, it seems to work fine now, looks like the commented $PathsToGrant = @() was the reason, even though it is declared as an array at the start of the script too, well it looks ok now anyway.

Comment: see my edited answer for an explanation